# ms-access remove fails on the same date from the same person when there is a pass

Tags: ms-access

Thank all of you for your help.  My Access database is coming along nicely.
My new question is:
I have three fields that are to be considered to get the result I am looking for.

Date, EMPID and the RESULTS field.
The date is simply a date with no time.
The EMPID is a unique employee identifier.
The Results field states either pass or fail.

What I am trying to do is on any single date (there may be many dates, but each is to be considered separately) an employee may test many times and have multiple failures (there can only ever be one passing result).   If on the same date the same employee passes, then all fails are to be removed.  If there is no pass, then leave one fail.

Thank You,

Comment: Just re-read and saw you need to 'not delete fails', thus you need a related table to store the fails.  Yes, you could use a text field and concatenate fails together, but that is a bad idea.

Comment: I just spoke to the quality manager and he is OK deleting the fails as long as there is one pass on that date.  I will try and change the main question to reflect this.

Comment: How are you updating your table - via a form? If so, than you can simply replace a 'Fail' with a 'Pass', but you need to prevent the opposite from being allowed (i.e. VBA code when you click a Save button). If you want to get more sophisticated - and stick with one table- you could add a counter for # of fails.

Comment: I personally wouldn't delete anything from the database simply for the quality assurance purposes. I would simply omit the records from display

Comment: The table is being updated from another program that doesn't have any logic to it.  It simply records.  After talking some more with the QA manager we agree not to delete records.  The reason for hiding any fails when there is a pass on the same date is for a report.  If we show all of these records the report gets very large.  The only fails we need are ones were there is no pass.

Comment: Reading your question and comments again, you do not mention if you have two related tables or not - and that updates are done by an external program with no logic. If you only have ONE table, then the final result will reflect the true status (i.e. if a PASS, never test again). But you also mention 'many dates'... so are there two tables or one?

Answer (score 0):

Query 1: QueryPass

SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE Results="Pass";

Query 2: QueryFail

SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE EmpID & ResDate Not In (SELECT EmpID & ResDate FROM QueryPass);

Query 3: QueryReport

SELECT EmpID, ResDate, Results FROM QueryFail
UNION SELECT EmpID, ResDate, Results FROM QueryPass;

NOTE: Date is a reserved word in Access, should avoid using reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: What I failed to mention is that this data comes from one table that has a query executed on it that reduces the shown data considerably.  The hope is to continue down this pass pulling the data from the query we have (Last Week).

Comment: @Mark since you now say there is only one table,  is there a row in the table for EVERY time a test is taken for an employee? If not, please explain how you are tracking multiple tests.

Comment: Fail to understand how that changes my suggested approach. If you want, instead of referencing table can reference query.

Comment: Yes there is a row for each test.  I just wanted to make sure the approach wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be multiple rows per person (and all in the same table), and if someone passes, it will be the 'last' record for that person, the following will give you what you need.

```
SELECT Last(Table1.[TestDate]) AS LastOfTestDate, 
      Table1.[EMPID], Last(Table1.[TestResult]) AS LastOfTestResult
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Table1.[EMPID];
```